# Automate Testing - Katalon studio

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I got an internship in some IT company and I have to learn how to test web apps and how to automate them.

I have never done it before so I am learning some stuff about Katalon Studio but honestly, I have no idea where to start, can you give me some clues and tips how to do it or what lecture read to find about how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install Katalon Studio :)
2. Register at www.katalon.com
3. Check out the tutorials (https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials)
4. I suggest, start by using Spy/Record features for an easy start
5. After you have recorded and replayed a few simple use cases, I suggest you should switch to making your own test scripts instead of the recorded ones (because they are realy good only for simple stuff)
6. Learn how to use css and xpath selectors
7. Ask further questions here and at forum.katalon.com

Happy testing!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try some samples from Katalon Help Page to have ready tests for API, Web UI and mobile. From sample projects, you can have some init ideas on how to setup a testing project using Katalon Studio.

[image: Katalon Studio sample projects]